# Flip X & Y coordinates for geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to flip both the X & Y axis to be descending as they move away from (0,0).  It seems that coord_flip() & scale_reverse should do the trick, but it seems to flip just one of the group variables and not the other?  It also seems to ignore the "breaks" statement, in that I would like the range of the bottom axis to run from 0 to 3%.

**EDIT:** This is what my chart looks like when I run the code:

[image: My Chart]

And this is the look I am trying to replicate:

[image: Chart to Replicate]

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


g0 <- data.table(year = rep(c(1790,1800,1810,1820,1830,1840,1850,1860,1870),2),
                 group = c(rep("A",9),rep("B",9)),
                 per = c(0.987,0.983,0.983,0.988,0.992,0.991,0.993,0.992,0,
                         0.013,0.017,0.017,0.012,0.008,0.009,0.007,0.008,1))

ggplot(g0, aes(x=year, y=per, fill=group)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.8, size=1) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = as.numeric(seq(1790, 1870, by=10))) +
  scale_y_reverse(position = "top", breaks = as.numeric(seq(0, 0.03, by=0.01))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#101010', '#CB0432')) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: When I run your code both axes are descending away from (0,0). Y is descending from 1870 to 1790 and X from 1 to 0. The breaks argument is working, it is just that you have included such small values that they are all being clumped around 0. Your axis goes from 0 to 1 and the only breaks you've provided are 0, 0.01, 0.02, and 0.03.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  That is correct, but I have edited my post to add how the chart renders for me.  Also, even though my range runs from 0 to 1, I would only like the bottom axis to run from 0 to 0.03 or 3%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your question is a little bit tricky because you are looking to zoom on the first 3 percent. If you just add limits to your y axis, you will get an empty plot because `ggplot2` will remove all values that are above 0.03 and all of your plotting area is linked together, so, if you remove one value, you get all the area removed.

So, I will show step by step how I get to the right plot using mainly `dplyr` and `tidyr` package for data manipulation (maybe there is easier solution) but if you jsut want the final plot, you can jump at the end.

First, you need to rescale your data in order to make 0.03 as the new maximum (instead of 1), like that the plot area will be comprise between 0 et 3%. This is easy as you just have to replace 1 by 0.03 and calculate A values based on this new maximum and the value of B:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
g0 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = per) %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(B == 1,0.03,B)) %>%
  mutate(A = 0.03-B) 

  year     A     B
1 1790 0.017 0.013
2 1800 0.013 0.017
3 1810 0.013 0.017
4 1820 0.018 0.012
5 1830 0.022 0.008
6 1840 0.021 0.009
7 1850 0.023 0.007
8 1860 0.022 0.008
9 1870 0.000 0.030
```

However, it is not correct because at the end, in your original plot, you have a progressive slope between 1860 and 1870 that go from 0.008 to 1. We need to recreate this slope in order to get the value of x when y  = 0.03:

```r
lm(per~year, data = df)

Call:
lm(formula = per ~ year, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         year  
  -184.5040       0.0992  

(0.03 +184.504) /0.0992
[1] 1860.222
```

So, now for y = 0.03, x = 1860.222. We will add this new row to the dataframe:

```r
g0 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = per) %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(B == 1,0.03,B)) %>%
  mutate(A = 0.03-B) %>%
  add_row(year = 1860.222, A = 0, B = 0.03) %>% arrange(year)

       year     A     B
1  1790.000 0.017 0.013
2  1800.000 0.013 0.017
3  1810.000 0.013 0.017
4  1820.000 0.018 0.012
5  1830.000 0.022 0.008
6  1840.000 0.021 0.009
7  1850.000 0.023 0.007
8  1860.000 0.022 0.008
9  1860.222 0.000 0.030
10 1870.000 0.000 0.030
```

We also need to switch from `geom_area` to `geom_ribbon` because our plot area is not going back to 0 a the end (for B values). But for that, we need to calculate `ymin` and `ymax` arguments:

```r
g0 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = per) %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(B == 1,0.03,B)) %>%
  mutate(A = 0.03-B) %>%
  add_row(year = 1860.222, A = 0, B = 0.03) %>% arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(ymin_B = 0, ymax_B = B, ymin_A = B, ymax_A = 0.03)

       year     A     B ymin_B ymax_B ymin_A ymax_A
1  1790.000 0.017 0.013      0  0.013  0.013   0.03
2  1800.000 0.013 0.017      0  0.017  0.017   0.03
3  1810.000 0.013 0.017      0  0.017  0.017   0.03
4  1820.000 0.018 0.012      0  0.012  0.012   0.03
5  1830.000 0.022 0.008      0  0.008  0.008   0.03
6  1840.000 0.021 0.009      0  0.009  0.009   0.03
7  1850.000 0.023 0.007      0  0.007  0.007   0.03
8  1860.000 0.022 0.008      0  0.008  0.008   0.03
9  1860.222 0.000 0.030      0  0.030  0.030   0.03
10 1870.000 0.000 0.030      0  0.030  0.030   0.03
```

Now, we are almost ready, just need a little bit of cleaning to get everything on the right shape:

```r
g0 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = per) %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(B == 1,0.03,B)) %>%
  mutate(A = 0.03-B) %>%
  add_row(year = 1860.222, A = 0, B = 0.03) %>% arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(ymin_B = 0, ymax_B = B, ymin_A = B, ymax_A = 0.03) %>%
  select(-c(A,B)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "group", values_to = "values")  %>%
  mutate(group2 = sub("\\_.","",group)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(group = unlist(strsplit(group,"_"))[2]) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group2, values_from = values)

# A tibble: 20 x 4
    year group  ymin  ymax
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1790  B     0     0.013
 2 1790  A     0.013 0.03 
 3 1800  B     0     0.017
 4 1800  A     0.017 0.03 
 5 1810  B     0     0.017
 6 1810  A     0.017 0.03 
 7 1820  B     0     0.012
 8 1820  A     0.012 0.03 
 9 1830  B     0     0.008
10 1830  A     0.008 0.03 
11 1840  B     0     0.009
12 1840  A     0.009 0.03 
13 1850  B     0     0.007
14 1850  A     0.007 0.03 
15 1860  B     0     0.008
16 1860  A     0.008 0.03 
17 1860. B     0     0.03 
18 1860. A     0.03  0.03 
19 1870  B     0     0.03 
20 1870  A     0.03  0.03
```

Now, we can add the plotting part and we get:

```r
g0 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = per) %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(B == 1,0.03,B)) %>%
  mutate(A = 0.03-B) %>%
  add_row(year = 1860.222, A = 0, B = 0.03) %>% arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(ymin_B = 0, ymax_B = B, ymin_A = B, ymax_A = 0.03) %>%
  select(-c(A,B)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "group", values_to = "values")  %>%
  mutate(group2 = sub("\\_.","",group)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(group = unlist(strsplit(group,"_"))[2]) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group2, values_from = values) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, fill = group))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = 0.8, size =  1)+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = as.numeric(seq(1790, 1870, by=10))) +
  scale_y_reverse(position = "top", breaks = seq(0,0.03, by=0.01))+
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#101010', '#CB0432')) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Hope it answers your question

Comment: Thanks dc37!  This is a very creative solution.  I appreciate the help.